# Darkcoin nomp pool payment processing error and missing ui

Tags: json, node.js

We are setting up nomp https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal

When we run

```
node init.js
```

This happens:

```
root@drk:~/node-open-mining-portal# node init.js
2014-05-17 18:51:17 [POSIX]     [Connection Limit] (Safe to ignore) POSIX module not installed and resource (connection) limit was not raised
2014-05-17 18:51:17 [Master]    [CLI] CLI listening on port 7777
2014-05-17 18:51:17 [Master]    [PoolSpawner] Spawned 1 pool(s) on 1 thread(s)
2014-05-17 18:51:17 [Profit]    [Config] No alternative coins to switch to in current config, switching disabled.
2014-05-17 18:51:17 [Switching] [Setup] (Thread 1) Loading last proxy state from redis
2014-05-17 18:51:17 [Pool]      [darkcoin] (Thread 1) Share processing setup with redis (127.0.0.1:6379)
2014-05-17 18:51:17 [Switching] [Setup] (Thread 1) Switching "switch1" listening for x11 on port 3333 into darkcoin
2014-05-17 18:51:23 [Pool]      [darkcoin] (Thread 1) Stratum Pool Server Started for darkcoin [DRK] {x11}
                                            Network Connected:      Mainnet
                                            Detected Reward Type:   POW
                                            Current Block Height:   70293
                                            Current Connect Peers:  7
                                            Current Block Diff:     2816.770470913
                                            Network Difficulty:     2755.22977025
                                            Network Hash Rate:      55.22 GH
                                            Stratum Port(s):        3331
                                            Pool Fee Percent:       1%
                                            Block polling every:    1000 ms
2014-05-17 18:52:18 [Pool]      [darkcoin] (Thread 1) No new blocks for 55 seconds - updating transactions & rebroadcasting work
2014-05-17 18:53:13 [Pool]      [darkcoin] (Thread 1) No new blocks for 55 seconds - updating transactions & rebroadcasting work
```

Then we navigate to our pool @ http://ourpoolexample.com/MPOS/public but we see a blank page. **Where is the UI?**

Here are our settings (user and password have been omitted):

**~/node-open-mining-portal/config.json**

```
{
"logLevel":                 "debug",
"logColors":                true,
"cliPort":                  7777,
"clustering":               {"enabled":true,"forks":"auto"},
"defaultPoolConfigs":{      "blockRefreshInterval":1000,
                            "jobRebroadcastTimeout":55,
                            "connectionTimeout":600,
                            "emitInvalidBlockHashes":true,
                            "validateWorkerUsername":true,
                            "tcpProxyProtocol":false,
                            "banning":{"enabled":true,"time":600,"invalidPercent":50,"checkThreshold":500,"purgeInterval":300},
                            "redis":{"host":"127.0.0.1","port":6379}},
"website":{                 "enabled":false,
                        "host":"0.0.0.0",
                        "port":80,
                        "stratumHost":"cryppit.com",
                        "stats":{"updateInterval":60,"historicalRetention":43200,"hashrateWindow":300},
                        "adminCenter":{"enabled":false,"password":"password"}},
"redis":                    {"host":"127.0.0.1","port":6379},
"switching":{
                        "switch1":{"enabled":true,"algorithm":"x11","ports":{
                            "3333":{"diff":32,"varDiff":{"minDiff":8,"maxDiff":512,"targetTime":15,"retargetTime":90,"variancePercent":30}}
                            }}
        },
"profitSwitch":         {"enabled":true,"updateInterval":600,"depth":0.90,"usePoloniex":true,"useCryptsy":true,"useMintpal":true}
}
```

**~/node-open-mining-portal/pool_configs/darkcoin.json**

```
{
"enabled":                  true,
"coin":                     "darkcoin.json",
"address":                  "XgZLPCQkGvvpK42jAAtgRHvs8J25xKn1XS",
"rewardRecipients":         {"XgZLPCQkGvvpK42jAAtgRHvs8J25xKn1XS":1.0},
"paymentProcessing":{       "enabled":false,
                            "paymentInterval":20,
                            "minimumPayment":70,
                            "daemon":{"host":"127.0.0.1","port":19332,"user":"user","password":"password"}},    
"ports":{                   "3331":{"diff":32,"varDiff":{"minDiff":8,"maxDiff":512,"targetTime":15,"retargetTime":90,"variancePercent":30}}},
"daemons":[                 {"host":"127.0.0.1","port":8332,"user":"user","password":"password"}],
"p2p":                      {"enabled":false,"host":"127.0.0.1","port":19333,"disableTransactions":true},
"mposMode":{                "enabled":false,
                            "host":"127.0.0.1",
                            "port":3306,
                            "user":"user",
                            "password":"password",
                            "database":"drk",
                            "checkPassword":true,
                            "autoCreateWorker":false}
}
```

**~/node-open-mining-portal/coins/darkcoin.json**

```
{
    "name": "Darkcoin",
    "symbol": "DRK",
    "algorithm": "x11",
    "mposDiffMultiplier": 256
}
```

**~/.darkcoin/darkcoin.conf**

```
server=1
gen=0
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
```

Notice we have disabled payment processing in pool_configs/darkcoin.json as we always get the error:

```
2014-05-17 19:21:19 [Payments]  [darkcoin] Error with payment processing daemon {"type":"offline","message":"connect ECONNREFUSED"}
```

I am assuming this may be a problem with ports conflicting but there is a line on the official page that confuses me on the payments processing main daemon:

```
/* This daemon is used to send out payments. It MUST be for the daemon that owns the
       configured 'address' that receives the block rewards, otherwise the daemon will not
       be able to confirm blocks or send out payments. */
```

It uses port 19332 twice in the example (matching), but when we match them the pool wont even start (another ECONNREFUSED this time for [pool])

What is the problem? We are very close..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your darkcoin.json, the ports for the daemons must match the rpcport in the respective daemons data directory conf file. Since 8332 is the rpc port in your darkcoin.conf in the data directory, this line:

```
"daemon":{"host":"127.0.0.1","port":19332,"user":"user","password":"password"}},
```

should be

```
"daemon":{"host":"127.0.0.1","port":8332,"user":"user","password":"password"}},
```